# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency. How do I fix this error?

Tags: reactjs

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency.

Line 92:4:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getMoviesData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Can someone tell me how to fix this error? I'm sure it's something very simple but any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function App() {

// * MOVIE API *


//State 
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
const [topMovies, setTopMovies] = useState([])
const [kidsMovies, setKidsMovies] = useState([])
const [setKidsTv] = useState([])
//kidsTv
const [setTvShows] = useState([])
//TvShows
const [kidsTvSeries, setKidsTvSeries] = useState([])




//API URL 
const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=&with_genres=28/';
const tvUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=8&language=en-US&page=1';
const kidsMovieURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=8&certification_country=US&certification.lte=G&with_genres=16&include_adult=false&sort_by=popularity.desc';
const kidsTvURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=8&language=en-US&page=1&with_genres=16&include_adult=false&sort_by=popularity.desc';
const topPicks = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=&language=en-US&page=1';
const kidsSeries = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?api_key=1f7c961ae4f02a23e0968d449c15bc98&with_genres=10762'

//Async function to fetch API
async function getMoviesData (url, tvUrl, topPicks, kidsMovieURL, kidsTvUrl, kidsSeries) {

  await fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setMovies(data.results))
  await fetch(topPicks).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTopMovies(data.results))
  await fetch(tvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTvShows(data.results))
  await fetch(kidsMovieURL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsMovies(data.results))
  await fetch(kidsTvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTv(data.results))
  await fetch(kidsSeries).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTvSeries(data.results))
}



//Use Effect 
 useEffect(() => { 
  getMoviesData(url, tvUrl, topPicks, kidsMovieURL, kidsTvURL, kidsSeries);

}, [])


  return (

    <div className='app'>

      <div className="header">
        <Header Home={Home} Movies={Movies} Kids={Kids} Music={lazyMusic} movies={movies} topMovies={topMovies} kidsMovies={kidsMovies} kidsTvSeries={kidsTvSeries} />
      </div>

      <div className="music-player">
        <MusicPlayer />
      </div>
  

    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `useEffect`, one thing to keep in mind is that any state variable or function that is defined inside the component and used inside the `effect` function (the 1st argument passed to `useEffect`) should be included in the dependency array (the 2nd argument).

In your component, you are using the `getMoviesData` function inside the `useEffect` hook, but you have not included that in the dependency array. That is why you are getting the linter warning. To fix this, you just have to add the function in the dependency array. So your `useEffect` hook will become this:

```js
useEffect(() => { 
  getMoviesData(url, tvUrl, topPicks, kidsMovieURL, kidsTvURL, kidsSeries);
}, [getMoviesData])
```

However, this creates a problem - this means that whenever the `getMoviesData` function is recreated, the effect will run once again. Since this function is updating the state, it will cause the component to re-render, which will then cause this function to be re-created, which in turn will cause the effect to run again, creating an infinite loop.

To solve this, you have a few options:

1. Move the `getMoviesData` inside the `useEffect`'s `effect` function (if you are not using it outside the `useEffect` hook)
2. Move it outside the component (if you are not interacting with state or any other component methods)
3. Wrap it with `useCallback` to memoize the function reference (if you are using the function outside the `useEffect`)

In your case, you need option #1.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  function getMoviesData (url, tvUrl, topPicks, kidsMovieURL, kidsTvUrl, kidsSeries) {
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setMovies(data.results))
    fetch(topPicks).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTopMovies(data.results))
    fetch(tvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTvShows(data.results))
    fetch(kidsMovieURL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsMovies(data.results))
    fetch(kidsTvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTv(data.results))
    fetch(kidsSeries).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTvSeries(data.results))
  }

  getMoviesData(url, tvUrl, topPicks, kidsMovieURL, kidsTvURL, kidsSeries);
}, [setMovies, setTopMovies, setKidsMovies, setKidsTv, setKidsTvSeries])
```

Comment: So move the whole async function 'getMoviesData' inside the useEffect function??

Comment: Yes. I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Also, you were using both `await` and `.then` to handle the `Promise` returned by the `fetch` calls. You only have to use one of them. I removed the usage of `await` since that was easier in this case.

Comment: Line 105:4:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'setKidsTv' and 'setTvShows'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

Comment: Any idea why i'ts now returning this error??

Comment: Ah, yes, you also have to add the state updating functions like `setKidsTv` to the dependency array as well. They will not cause the component to re-render.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to memorize the function using `useCallback` and add the `getMoviesData` to the dependency array of the `useEffect`.

```
  const getMoviesData = useCallback(async () => {
    await fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setMovies(data.results))
    await fetch(topPicks).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTopMovies(data.results))
    await fetch(tvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTvShows(data.results))
    await fetch(kidsMovieURL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsMovies(data.results))
    await fetch(kidsTvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTv(data.results))
    await fetch(kidsSeries).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTvSeries(data.results))
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => { 
      getMoviesData(url, tvUrl, topPicks, kidsMovieURL, kidsTvURL, kidsSeries);
    
    }, [getMoviesData])
```

Comment: It still returns an error

Comment: Line 76:1:  The 'getMoviesData' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 92) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'getMoviesData' in its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: Any idea what to do??

Comment: @Gavin-walsh I have updated the answer with `useCallback`

Answer (score 0):

You should move `getMoviesData func` inside `callback of useEffect` like this:

```
//Use Effect 
 useEffect(() => { 
  //Async function to fetch API
  async function getMoviesData (url, tvUrl, topPicks, kidsMovieURL, kidsTvUrl, kidsSeries) {
    await fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setMovies(data.results))
    await fetch(topPicks).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTopMovies(data.results))
    await fetch(tvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTvShows(data.results))
    await fetch(kidsMovieURL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsMovies(data.results))
    await fetch(kidsTvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTv(data.results))
    await fetch(kidsSeries).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTvSeries(data.results))
  }
  getMoviesData(url, tvUrl, topPicks, kidsMovieURL, kidsTvURL, kidsSeries);

}, [])
```

---

Or another way, you can put `getMoviesData func` outside `useEffect`, but you need add `useCallback` for `getMoviesData` like this:

```
    const getMoviesData = useCallback(async (url, tvUrl, topPicks, kidsMovieURL, kidsTvUrl, kidsSeries) => {
      await fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setMovies(data.results))
      await fetch(topPicks).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTopMovies(data.results))
      await fetch(tvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTvShows(data.results))
      await fetch(kidsMovieURL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsMovies(data.results))
      await fetch(kidsTvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTv(data.results))
      await fetch(kidsSeries).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTvSeries(data.results))
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])
    
    useEffect(() => { 
      getMoviesData(url, tvUrl, topPicks, kidsMovieURL, kidsTvURL, kidsSeries);
    }, [getMoviesData])
```

Answer (score -1):

Mayve you could try something like that (using useCallback):

```
const getMoviesData = useCallback(() => { /* your code */ }, []);
```